# Bash- Using the 'find' command for testing

Tags: bash

I want to know if there's any way to use the 'find' command in bash for testing. in other words, how do I go about making a conditional statement that tests whether a file was found with 'find' or not?

To expound more on what I mean, I've included the following code. The purpose of which should:

1. find a directory inputted by user
2. find a file in that directory, filename inputted by user
3. find a word in that file, which is also inputted by user

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#Task9.sh
cd /
echo "please enter a directory"
read direc
path= find home -depth -name "$direc" 
if [ -z $path ]; then
    echo "not a valid directory"
    exit 1
else
    cd $path
    counter=3
    while [ $counter -gt 0 ]; do
        echo "enter a filename"
        read FileName
        FilePath= find $direc -depth -name "$FileName"
        if [ -z $FilePath ]; then
            break
        else
                let counter--
    fi  
    done
if [ -z $FilePath ]; then 
            cd $FilePath        
            echo "input a word"
            read SearchWord
            echo "Found!"
            grep $SearchWord $FileName

    else
           echo "No such file"
           exit 2
    fi
fi

exit 0
```

I'm very new to Bash, so I apologize for any easy mistakes I have overlooked. I'm not used to parsing the language yet. Thank you to anyone who helps me, it is greatly appreciated

Comment: are you required to use the `find` command?  are you required to use the -z operator?  Or can you use other commands and operators?

Comment: I can use other operators, I just generally don't know how to test for the non-existence of a file in a directory.

Comment: Your assignments are wrong, you cannot have a space after an equals sign, and the stuff after the equals sign will be a literal string where apparently you want command substitution. `path=` sets the variable to an empty string, `path=foo bar` runs the command `bar` with `path` temporarily set to `foo`; normally, you quote a literal value, `path='foo bar'` or `path="foo bar"` but here you want command substitution: `path=$(foo bar)` or old-style `path=\`foo bar\`` to run the command `foo bar` and capture its output in `path`.

Comment: You should generally double-quote your variable interpolations unless you specifically want the shell to perform word splitting and wildcard expansion on the value, which I guess you will not want to for another couple of years at least. So `"$variable"` instead of an unquoted bare `$variable` throughout.

Answer (score 1):

you're using the `find` command plus the shell's `-z $foo` operator to figure out whether or not the user has specified the path to an existing file.  There might be a way just to ask bash directly if the file exists or not, using a file-based operator, instead of running an unnecessary command and then using a string-based operator on the result (hint: there is).  Some of the links on this page might help you:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tests.html

good luck!